# Mathematica and its default assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am a bit surprised that evsluating

```
Integrate[Exp[I n x],{x, 0, Pi}]
```

gives

$\qquad \frac{-i(e^{in\pi}-1)}{n}$.

What if $n = 0$? I didn't assume anything about $n$ and yet Mathematica assumes $n\neq 0$.

It is the same with the Maxima command :

```
integrate(exp(%i*n*x),x,0,%pi);
```

and the Maple command

```
int(exp(n*x*I), x = 0 .. PI)
```

How do I handle this kind of behavior which I consider undesirable?

What is the name of this feature in symbolic computation, so that I can find a solution for Maxima as well.

Comment: That is the General solution that Mathematica shows. Simplification isn’t needed unless a specific forbidden value is chosen. User72028 shows then how the limit can be taken to manage for this. I would not consider it an error.

Comment: ...and cvgmt gave the example I was going to give: consider the simpler `Integrate[x^a, x]` and note that the "singular" case is not included in the generic answer given.

Comment: You can use `Piecewise` to make it explicit: `int = Piecewise[{{Integrate[Exp[I n x], {x, 0, Pi}], n != 0}, {Integrate[Exp[I n x] /. n -> 0, {x, 0, Pi}], n == 0}}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$n = 0$ is a removable singularity. If you take the limit of the result of the integral, you will get the same as if you put $n = 0$ before taking the integral:

```
result = Integrate[Exp[I n x], {x, 0, Pi}]

Limit[result, n -> 0]
(* Pi *)

Integrate[Exp[I 0 x], {x, 0, Pi}]
(* Pi *)
```

### Addendum

Re @cvgmt on `Integrate[x^a, x]` for `a = -1`: that also is a removable singularity (provided the constant of integration is chosen correctly). We have
$$
  \int_1^x u^a \,\mathrm{d}u = \frac{x^{a+1} - 1}{a+1},
$$
and
$$
  \lim_{a \to -1} \frac{x^{a+1} - 1}{a+1} = \log x.
$$

In general Mathematica does not bother with treating removable singularities separately. For example, `x/x` will simplify to `1` *without* any assumptions on `x`.

Comment: so when the singularity can't be removed, it doesn't simplify ? Do you know on which mathematical (surely from singularity theory) theorem this features comes from ?

Comment: @user72028  `Integrate[x^a, x]` why does not consider the case `a= -1`